# How can I stretch a DIV to full-screen upon clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, css

I've got an image, and I'm just trying to stretch it to full-screen by clicking anywhere on the image.  So, I made the image the background of a DIV.  I'm having trouble with the javascript: specifically, targeting the CSS.  Please, let me know by using jsfiddle.

Here is my current attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/Muimi/hSzq7/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('.beforeClick').click(function (){
       $('.beforeClick').css(div#stretch'width',"33fpx");
           $(this).css(div#stretch'width',"100%");
   });
});

div#stretch{
  height: 334px;
  width: 640px;
  background-image: url(http://i.investopedia.com/inv/articles/slideshow/6-generic-products/generic-just-as-good.jpg);
}

<body>
    <div id="stretch"></div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#stretch').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
});
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

div#stretch{
  height: 334px;
  width: 640px;
  background-image: url(http://i.investopedia.com/inv/articles/slideshow/6-generic-products/generic-just-as-good.jpg);
}

div#stretch.fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSzq7/18/)

Comment: Adding to your answer, you can also use background-size: cover; to remove any borders by cropping the image. See http://jsfiddle.net/hSzq7/22/

Comment: @David Hewitt I decided against `cover` as it crops the image. Only a guess but I'm assuming the OP wants the full image

Comment: Yep, just throwing it in there as another option. Generally backgrounds are designed to fill their entire container. OP can use either solution.

Comment: Yeah, this is a really cool answer.  I like how the code is compartmentalized.

Comment: Trying to do this for videos, with outside buttons, also: http://jsfiddle.net/Muimi/hSzq7/39/.

Comment: You missed some quote marks. `$(#stretch).toggleClass('fullscreen');` should be `$('#stretch').toggleClass('fullscreen');` http://jsfiddle.net/hSzq7/40/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not correct. Check out this syntax and edit it by yourself.

> http://jsfiddle.net/hSzq7/12/

```
$(function(){
  $('div#stretch').click(function (){
    $(this).css('height',"33px").css('width',"100%");
  });
});
```

Is important to set `html` and `body` height to `100%`

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Dude, did you notice that when you set 'height', "100%", the image disappears?

Comment: Because you didn't set the `HTML` and `BODY` height to `100%`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding/removing a class on click, rather than changing the attributes in "this" class?  You could even use an if else statement, off the top of my head I can't recreate the code verbatim.

Consider:

```
$(function() {                       
$(".clickable").click(function() {
$(this).addClass("stretched");
});
});
```

What this allows you to do is have two separate CSS classes one of which will only become active when the image in clicked, and the other when it is not.

P.S, Marcell is also correct.  By all means use 100%, but there are alternatives.

Consider:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kgkXT/ ?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('#stretch').click(function (){
       $(this).css('width',"100%");
   });
});
```

And in the CSS set

```
background-size:100% auto;
```

Comment: So the id goes after $(', and the rule goes after .css(, right?

Comment: No offense but your syntax was so completely off and jquery wasn't even included in your fiddle. I'd suggest reading http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ and/or learn the basic syntax of javascript.

Comment: Yeah, bud.  It's true.  I've learned and re-learned it, but I don't do it professionally.  I really need to create a good resource list with personalized reference marks.